# How can i say, while counter < len of list_states, apend the lambda 's value which is not ''?

Tags: python

I want to say if A state (which is start state) goes to lambda with a transition which is not empty, then where is going lambda 's transition with lambda again
for examle A goes to B with lambda
i want to say while counter < length(list_states): then say if B goes to a state with lambda print it
and counter += 1

```
nfa = {
    'A': {
        '0': 'B',
        '1': '',
        'lambda': 'B'},
    'B': {
        '0': ['A', 'C'],
        '1': ['B', 'C'],
        'lambda': 'C'},
    'C': {
        '0': 'C',
        '1': 'B',
        'lambda': 'C'}
}

list_states = []
for key in nfa:
    list_states.append(key)  # function for getting keys in nfa dictionary
print(list_states)

def findLength():  # Function which is used for return length
    count = 0
    for i in list_states:
        count += 1
    print(count)
    return count

def starter_state():
    start_state = list_states[0]
    count_state = findLength()
    Counter1 = 0
    if nfa[start_state[0]]['lambda'] != '':
        dfa_start_state = start_state + nfa[start_state[0]]['lambda']
        # print(list(dfa_start_state))
```

Comment: You can use `list(nfs)` to convert the keys to a list. And `findLength()` is just `len(list_states)`.

Comment: None of the `lambda` values are empty. What is the end state?

Comment: The end state is C.

Comment: you can just use a `for` loop: `for counter in range(count_state):`

Comment: Lambdas can change .
in my example just A 's lambda is full and the others are empty.